# Can an Android app only allow itself to be installed on devices with a magnetic sensor?

Tags: android, magnetometer

Can an Android app only allow itself to be installed from Google Play on devices with a magnetic sensor (compass)?

Is it possible to restrict target devices in other ways?

Comment: Use `<uses-feature` with the magnetic sensor and set required to true. It will **not block the install**, but it will hide it from incompatible devices in GOogle Play. Anyone with the APK can still install it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.sensor.compass"
  android:required="true" />
```

See more details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

As @Zoe mentioned, it will hide on Play Store but not Block installation if someone has the APK. If you want to block the use of app then you can add a check in your starting activity and prevent user from using any feature.

```
PackageManager mgr = getPackageManager();
boolean hasCompass = mgr.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_COMPASS);
```